# Differentiability class of quadratic function

Tags: calculus

What is the differentiability class of the quadratic function?

I think it's class $C^{\infty}$, because deriving this function 3 times we'll get a constant function, $g(x) = 0$. Witch the derivative is itself. What I'm making some trouble is that, there are some functions, such as $e^x$ that are class $C^{\infty}$ too. But their derivatives never leads to $0$.

Generalizing and questioning:

Polynomial functions are of class $C^{\infty}$? If they are, there are any distinction or classification between this two kinds of functions(functions of class $C^{\infty}$, that has $D_x^n = 0, n \in \mathbb{N}$;and functions of the same class that $D_x^n \neq 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ and as $n$ goes to infinity.)

Comment: As long as you can always take the next derivative, it is $C^\infty$.  It doesn't matter what that derivative is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [definition of a smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Differentiability_classes), $\,f\in C^\infty\,$ if and only if it has derivatives $\,f^{\left(k\right)}\,$ of all orders $\,k\in \mathbb N\,$.

As you outlined, given polynomial  $\,P_n\,$ of order $\,n\in \mathbb N\,$ its  derivative $\, P^{\left(k\right)}_n\, $ of the order $\, k = n + 1\,$ will be zero.
However, one can keep differentiating constant zero functions as many times as one wants, and keep getting zeros. 
Thus, derivatives of all order exist, so the polynomial belongs to the class of smooth functions: $\,P_n \in C^\infty.\,$

**PS**: 
To my knowledge, there is no special notation for neither  set of infinitely differentiable functions whose derivatives starting from a certain number are all zeros, nor for the functions whose derivatives are all non-zero.
As long as it is possible to keep taking derivatives of a function, it belongs to corresponding differentiability class, regardless of whether the derivatives are zeros or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very enlightening! :)